# Unable to check/uncheck specific checkbox based on text

Tags: ruby, checkbox, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir

I am trying to check and uncheck checkboxes based on following requirements:

1. If a particular text is present, I need to check the checkbox for it.
2. If some other text has checkbox set, I need to uncheck that checkbox

   ```
   <table class="adm">
     <tbody>
      <tr class="action">
       <td width="20px">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
       </td>
       <td>
        <span class="label">
         <script id="start"></script>
         Action1
         <script id="end"></script>
        </span>

        <p class="desc">
        <script id="start"></script>
        Description1
        <script id="end"></script>
        </p>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>

   <table class="adm">
     <tbody>
      <tr class="action">
       <td width="20px">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
       </td>
       <td>
        <span class="label">
         <script id="start"></script>
         Action2
         <script id="end"></script>
        </span>

        <p class="desc">
        <script id="start"></script>
        Description2
        <script id="end"></script>
        </p>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

And there are 5 checkbox classes like the one above.
So , I need to check :

- Find "Action1" -> check it's checkbox.
- If "Action2" has checkbox set -> uncheck that checkbox.

So, need to set checkbox as per requirements and uncheck all other checkboxes.

I found this to check/uncheck all checkboxes:

```
checkbox_class = /checkbox/
  @browser.checkboxes(:class => checkbox_class).each do |checkbox|
    if(!checkbox.checked?)
      p "checkbox not set"
      checkbox.set
    else
      p "checkbox set"
      checkbox.clear
    end
  end
```

But I am unable to cater this as per my requirements, tried this:

```
checkbox_class = /checkbox/
action_class = /label/

  @browser.checkboxes(:class => checkbox_class).each do |checkbox|
    if(!@browser.span(:class=>action_class,:text=>"some_action").checkbox.checked?)
      p "checkbox not set"
      checkbox.set
    else
      p "checkbox set"
      checkbox.clear
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your loop and your conditional are out of sync.
`@browser.span(:class=>action_class,:text=>"some_action").checkbox`
is the same thing as:
`@browser.span(:class=>action_class,:text=>"some_action").checkbox(:index => 0)`
It refers to the same element on the page, regardless of the checkbox in your loop.

It might be easiest to uncheck all checkboxes with the code you found, then find checkbox with the action you want and just check that box.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the labels and checkboxes are related by their shared ancestor, the table element, I think it is easier to iterate through the tables. Within each table, you can check the label text and then decided whether to set/clear the checkbox.

The following will set the "Action1" checkbox and uncheck the rest:

```
action = 'Action1'
browser.tables(:class => 'adm').each do |table|

  # Check if the label matches the action we want to check
  value = (table.span(:class => 'label').text == action)

  # Set the checkbox if the label matches, otherwise clears
  table.checkbox.set(value)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will work:

action_trs = @browser.trs(class: ‘action’)

```
action_trs.each do |action_tr|
  if action_tr.td(index: 1).span.text == ‘some_action’
    action_tr.checkbox.set unless action_tr.checkbox.set?
  else
    action_tr.checkbox.clear
  end
end
```

Good luck! :)